# Javascript reduce function doesn't work on this obj

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, reduce, dom-events

I am new to Javascript and trying to execute below code on parent object but it is not working as expected. Please help.

The below code doesn't work as expected and throws error as:

> "TypeError: this.reduce is not a function"

```
Array.prototype.merge = merge = this.reduce(function(arg1,arg2)   {
    return arg1+arg2;
},[]);

var arrays =  [1,2,3,4,5,6];
console.log(arrays.merge);
```

It throws error as below:

```
TypeError: this.reduce is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\merge.js:1:100)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
```

If I call array directly, it works fine but that is not what I want to do. I should be able to pass array as shown on above example code.

```
Array.prototype.merge = merge = [1,2,3,4,5,6].reduce(function(arg1,arg2)   {
    return arg1+arg2;
},[]);

console.log(arrays.merge);
```

Comment: It's because in your code, `this` isn't set to the array object, it's set to the global object.

Comment: Thank you for answering this @OceansOnPluto but how do I refer "this" to array object and call "arrays.merge" the way I have showed in the example?

Comment: First, what are you trying to do? What do you want your intended return to be?

Comment: it should print 123456 to me when I call "consol.log(arrays.merge)"

Comment: Minor but important note, you need to call `arrays.merge()` instead of `arrays.merge`. The lack of parens would make it return the function object rather than running the function code. (Once you get the other problem fixed.)

Comment: @DanLowe, Yes. If I convert merge into function the way OcensOnPluto showed in his answer than it should work fine but I am wondering whether it is possible by arrays.merge and pass that arrays value to some other block of code and do processing on arrays actual value. in my second code.

Comment: isn't the result the same as [1,2,3,4,5,6].join('')

Comment: @JaromandaX, yes. It is same but I was playing more with reduce method and check how it behaves/works etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick!

```
Array.prototype.merge = function () {
    return this.reduce(function (arg1, arg2) {return arg1 + arg2;},[]);
};
```

By the way, this works because in this case, `this` is the object that the method is being called on, which is your merge function.

Comment: yes that works but wondering whether it is possible with variable rather than merge as function. I want to do "consol.log(arrays.merge)" and it should print result 123456. is this possible? Sorry if I am asking some stupid question but I am new to javascript and coming from more on java world. As I have mentioned above, if I replace this with direct array call on reduce function than it works as expected but I am not able to do dynamic using "this".

Comment: No it's alright. Never feel bad for asking! But as far as I can tell, that's not possible without modifying the Array constructor, and I'm not totally sure you can do that. You'd need to have it as a function that you can invoke. However, can I ask the use case? Is calling `console.log(theArray.merge())` that different from calling `console.log(theArray.merge)`? What's the use case you're after?

Comment: I can use method rather than variable thats fine but wondering how does that make difference in javascript works. Below works fine when executing below code but it doen't work if I pass this instead.  Array.prototype.merge = merge = [1,2,3,4,5,6].reduce(function(arg1,arg2)   {
    return arg1+arg2;
},[]);
arrays = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
console.log(arrays.merge);

Comment: So, is my answer the accepted one, the one you were looking for? Or you're still unclear? Not sure what you mean. :)

Comment: Yes. Answer is perfect. Thank you. But just wondering how does that make difference in javascript works. Below works fine when executing below code but it doen't work if I pass "this" instead. Array.prototype.merge = merge = [1,2,3,4,5,6].reduce(function(arg1,arg2) { return arg1+arg2; },[]); arrays = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; console.log(arrays.merge);

Comment: If you use `this` outside of a function then it is a reference to the global object (the window in a browser, or a special global scope object in Node.js). Inside a function, it is a reference to the caller. Educating you fully on how `this` and prototypal inheritance actually work is a bit much to do here though. Did you read the link show-me-the-code included in their answer?

Comment: Yes I just saw that URL and I think I got it. One last question, is there any other way to pass "arrays" variable value to reduce method other than using "this" keyword? Again this is just for information purpose and might be deviating from my original question. :)

Comment: Nope, `this` is what you'd have to do.

Comment: OK. Nice. Thank you for answering @OceansOnPluto. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Object.defineProperty - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'merge', {
  get: function() { return this.join(''); },
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: true
});
```

or - using reduce

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'merge', {
  get: function() { 
    return this.reduce(function (arg1, arg2) {
      return arg1 + arg2;
     }, []); 
  },
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: true
});
```

This code will allow you to do what you've said in a couple of comments

```
console.log([1,2,3,4,5].merge);
```

instead of

```
console.log([1,2,3,4,5].merge());
```

Comment: Sweet. Interesting that I can define properties like this. Thank you @JaromandaX

Comment: by the way, for Arrays especially, it's most important to have `enumerable: false` - otherwise some (old and stupid) libraries that use `for...in` on arrays will fail in interesting ways (I'm looking at you **telerik** )

Answer (score 0):

I would add a merge function to the `Array.prototype` like this:

```
Array.prototype.merge = function () {
    return this.reduce(function (arg1, arg2) {
        return +arg1 + +arg2;
    }, []);
};


var arrays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
console.log(arrays.merge());
```

More about the `this` keyword in Javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Thank you for answering this. I was able to make this working using function but that is not what I want to do here. I want to do "consol.log(arrays.merge)" and it should print result 123456. is this possible? As I have mentioned above, if I replace this with direct array call on reduce function than it works as expected but I am not able to do dynamic using "this".